# how to change notification maximum number in a day for GCP Monitoring Alert Policy

Tags: google-cloud-platform, monitoring

For some reasons, I want to increase the maximum number of notification in a day. However, I cannot find the way and the related price. The number is 20 now. So how can I improve it?
I can find the quota link and see the basic config in the picture below.

I hope you can give me the way to increase the number or link.

Answer (score 0):

*Alert policies* contains *alert strategies*, with strategies you can handle ***notifications rate limits*** which lets you to **Not receive more than one notification per period**. If you manipulates the period window then you will vary the quantity notifications per day.

Go to this documentation page and search for "*alert_strategy*"
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/monitoring_alert_policy

Hope I could help you.